# How can I combine the schema and multi-steps with formkit?

Tags: formkit

I do not yet know the number of steps required and would like to load the form highly dynamically. Unfortunately I could not find anything in the documentation.

```
      <FormKit type="multi-step" tab-style="tab">
        <FormKit type="step" name="personalInfo">
          <!-- component for example brevity. -->
          <StepOne />
        </FormKit>

        <FormKit type="step" name="new">
          <!-- component for example brevity. -->
          
        </FormKit>
        <FormKit type="step" name="references">
            <!-- component for example brevity. -->
            <StepTwo />
        </FormKit>

        <FormKit type="step" name="Supplemental">
          <!-- component for example brevity. -->
          <StepThree />

          <!-- using step slot for submit button-->
          <template #stepNext>
            <FormKit type="submit" />
          </template>
        </FormKit>
      </FormKit>
```